# Creating "List Box" custom field in Infusionsoft using its API

Tags: infusionsoft

We need to create a [List Box](https://helpcenterimages.s3.amazonaws.com/admin/settings/custom-fields14.png) type of [custom field](https://help.infusionsoft.com/help/choose-custom-field-types) thru the API. If we follow [this guide](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/#data-create-a-custom-field), we can create Text, Dropdown, and TextArea custom fields except the ones not mentioned (in our case, we need "List Box"). But it didn't give any idea on what to use for the **data type** part of it.

[image: infusionsoft-listbox]

We tried experimenting with possible data type values but it still returns the same "invalid type" error as above. What we have tried so far are:

```
List Box
ListBox
List
Box
Options
Option
Option List
OptionList
Options List
Option Lists
Options Lists
```

**QUESTION**

Is there a guide somewhere that we may have missed looking at? Or is it even possible to create a List Box custom field thru the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating this post for future reference.
Just sent a dev ticket to Infusionsoft, and they advised to use “MultiSelect”. It works now!

```
array:4 [▼
  "customFieldType" => "Contact"
  "displayName" => "XXXXX"
  "dataType" => "MultiSelect" // <-- this works
  "headerId" => 47
]
```